# How can I convert long to int in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, type-conversion, integer, long-integer

This HTML file calculate the difference in days between the current date and a selected date as long as it is later than today.
The final output shows how many days there are between the two dates, but I can't convert it from long to int.
Can anyone solve this problem?

here the codes:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Calcolo distanza</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="myFunction()">
    <p> Data corrente </p>
    <button type="button" id="myBtn"></button>
    <p> Scegli la data </p>
    <input type="date" id="dataCorrente">
    <input type="submit" onclick="calcola()">
    <br>
    <p id="Risultato"> </p>

    </body>
    <script>
        var d= new Date();
        function myFunction(){
            console.log("onload()");
            console.log(d);
            document.getElementById("myBtn").innerHTML=d.toDateString();
        }
        function calcola(){
            var input = document.getElementById("dataCorrente").value;
            if(input!=null){
                var dat=new Date();
                dat.setHours(0);
                dat.setMinutes(0);
                dat.setSeconds(0);
                var data = new Date(input); 
                var mill1=dat.getTime();
                var mill2=data.getTime();
                if(mill2>mill1){
                    mill2=mill2-mill1;
                    var ris=mill2/86400000;
                    document.getElementById("Risultato").innerHTML=ris;
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("Risultato").innerHTML="La data deve essere maggiore di quella corrente";
                }
            }
            else{
                console.log("input=null");
                document.getElementById("Risultato").innerHTML="Data non inserita";
            }
        }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: @Spectric line 36  document.getElementById("Risultato").innerHTML=ris;   this shows the output as a long value but I have to converte it as a long number

Comment: Maybe you want to round the number to an integer?  [Math.round](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Comment: There's no such thing as a "long integer" in JavaScript. All numbers are double-precision 64-bit floating point values (IEEE 754). There is some surface support for integers as numbers with the decimal portion set to 0.

Comment: @James yes but Spectric just resolved it with parseInt()

Comment: parseInt will chop off the decimal, if you want it rounded use round.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `parseInt()` function like so:

```js
var d = new Date();

function myFunction() {
  /*console.log("onload()");
  console.log(d);*/
  document.getElementById("myBtn").innerHTML = d.toDateString();
}

function calcola() {
  var input = document.getElementById("dataCorrente").value;
  if (input != null) {
    var dat = new Date();
    dat.setHours(0);
    dat.setMinutes(0);
    dat.setSeconds(0);
    var data = new Date(input);
    var mill1 = dat.getTime();
    var mill2 = data.getTime();
    if (mill2 > mill1) {
      mill2 = mill2 - mill1;
      var ris = mill2 / 86400000;
      document.getElementById("Risultato").innerHTML = parseInt(ris);
    } else {
      document.getElementById("Risultato").innerHTML = "La data deve essere maggiore di quella corrente";
    }
  } else {
    console.log("input=null");
    document.getElementById("Risultato").innerHTML = "Data non inserita";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calcolo distanza</title>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  <p> Data corrente </p>
  <button type="button" id="myBtn"></button>
  <p> Scegli la data </p>
  <input type="date" id="dataCorrente">
  <input type="submit" onclick="calcola()">
  <br>
  <p id="Risultato"> </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This does not convert anything from "long" to "int", since such terms are irrelevant in JavaScript.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes but I mean what I needed was to show onlu the numbers before the decimal point since the days were already calculated

Answer (score 1):

I set `data.setHours(0);` because the time zone thingy with date was causing some problems, and it just resets the hours. After that, it seems to work.

Try this:

```js
var d = new Date();

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myBtn").innerHTML = d.toDateString();
}

function calcola() {
  var input = document.getElementById("dataCorrente").value;
  if (input != null) {
    var dat = new Date();
    dat.setHours(0);
    dat.setMinutes(0);
    dat.setSeconds(0);
    dat.setMilliseconds(0);
    var data = new Date(input);
    data.setHours(0);
    var mill1 = dat.getTime();
    var mill2 = data.getTime();
    if (data > dat) {
      mill2 = data - dat;
      console.log(data)
      console.log(dat)
      var ris = mill2 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 1000;
      document.getElementById("Risultato").innerHTML = ris;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("Risultato").innerHTML = "La data deve essere maggiore di quella corrente";
    }
  } else {
    console.log("input=null");
    document.getElementById("Risultato").innerHTML = "Data non inserita";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calcolo distanza</title>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  <p> Data corrente </p>
  <button type="button" id="myBtn"></button>
  <p> Scegli la data </p>
  <input type="date" id="dataCorrente">
  <input type="submit" onclick="calcola()">
  <br>
  <p id="Risultato"> </p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Emdothermic_Dragon true, I had not consider this thing thanks a lot for the advice